# ReferenceError angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Many times answered, but I still don't understand what's wrong in my code. I'm new to JavaScript and Angular, so please help why I'm getting this error.

Here's my HTML and JavaScript codes. I'm trying to make an array from user input values, show them in table and then insert a button to calculate the cheapest and the most expensive items of the list. Right now I'm stuck in getting the user inputs in the array because of the angular error.

```js
var listaArr = [];
var app = angular.module("ostosLista", []);
app.controller("listaKontrolleri", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.listaArr = [{"syotettyTuote": "syotettyHinta"}];
}]);

var syotettyTuote = $scope.document.getElementById("tuote");
var syotettyHinta = $scope.document.getElementById("hinta");

function lisaaListaanTuote(){
    $scope.listaArr.push($scope.syotettyTuote.value);
}
function lisaaListaanHinta(){
    $scope.listaArr.push($scope.syotettyHinta.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="ostosLista">
    <head>
        <title>Budjetti</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="listaKontrolleri">
       <h1>Listasi</h1>
       <table>
       <tr ng-repeat="syotettyTuote and syotettyHinta in listaArr">
           <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
           <td>{{ x.syotettyTuote }}</td>
           <td>{{ x.syotettyHinta }}</td>
       </tr>
       </table>
       <form>
           <fieldset>
               <legend>Listaan</legend>
               <input id="tuote" type="text" ng-model="syotettyTuote" placeholder="Tuote" />
               <button ng-click="lisaaListaanTuote()">Laita listaan</button>
               <input id="hinta" type="parseInt" ng-model="syotettyHinta" placeholder="Hinta" />
               <button ng-click="lisaaListaanHinta()">Laita listaan</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <h2>Listasi kallein ja halvin tuote</h2>
        <button id="laske" onclick="laske()" placeholder="Laske kallein ja halvin tuote">Laske kallein         ja halvin</button>
        <textarea id="kallein" placeholder="Kallein" ></textarea>
        <textarea id="halvin" placeholder="Halvin"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share with us your error

Comment: ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Inari\Documents\visual studio code\lisätehtävä lista\js\script.js:2:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)…

Comment: And here's rest of it:


at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)

Comment: You're using the `$scope` outside controller

Answer (score 0):

You've used `$scope` object outside the `Controller` and the code language is a bit difficult to understand.

However, I've added the simple example from your code.

```js
var listaArr = [];
var app = angular.module("ostosLista", []);
app.controller("listaKontrolleri", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.listaArr = [];
 
 $scope.lisaaListaanTuote = function(){
  
    var val = angular.element(document.querySelector("#tuote")).val();
      
      console.log(val);
    
  $scope.listaArr.push(val);
 }
 
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="ostosLista">
    <head>
        <title>Budjetti</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="listaKontrolleri">
       <h1>Listasi</h1>
       <table>
       <tr ng-repeat="item in listaArr">
           <td>{{item}}</td>
       </tr>
       </table>
       <form>
           <fieldset>
               <legend>Listaan</legend>
               <input id="tuote" type="text" placeholder="Tuote" />
               <button ng-click="lisaaListaanTuote()">Laita listaan</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh dear. I knew the answer is simple, but still I couldn't figure it out. Many thanks!

Comment: But now that I tried that, Visual code debugger still says that angular is not defined. In the browser adding item to the list works, but when I try to see the array in console, there's nothing in it:

[object Array]: []

undefined

Comment: Your Initial array has `Key:Value` pair but what you're trying to do in push? You're just adding input values to array. What is your requirement?

Comment: In my first attempt there's two inputs. First is for an item and the second is for the price of the item. That's why I had a Key:Value pair. After getting an array right, my aim is to make functions to calculate and show the cheapest and the most expensive items of the array.